# Generating PDF/A using EvoPDF is not valid PDF/A

Tags: pdf-generation, pdfa, evopdf

I'm trying to generate PDF/A-1b document from a website using EvoPDF v3.0

When I verify the output using Adobe Preflight, I get the validation error "CIDSet in subset font missing"

Is there a way to work around this problem, or can someone suggest a different HTML to PDF generator capable of generating PDF/A-1b which doesn't use IE for rendering?

Comment: There's a webkit-based one called wkhtmltopdf but I don't know if you can specify standards to conform to. http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer this myself.

```
pdfConverter.UseCrossRefStreams = false;
```